# combining bootstrap modal with drag and drop

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, drag-and-drop

I have used bootstrap to create a modal for uploading an album art for creating an album. Until now I was using basic html method for uploading files using  until I came across drag and drop. I found the popular dropzone plugin and thought I should give it a try. I am not familiar with jquery/ajax and failed miserably. I have the following requirements:

- The form will be submitted only after clicking the Submit button(input type being "button")
- Only one file can be dropped
- An image preview section inside the modal
- An option to remove the image
- A progress bar

I have been searching for answers for so many hours but I can't find the right solution. Can anyone please solve this puzzle for me? I have attached the modal code below. I am using PHP as my server side scripting language. Thanks

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-folder"> </i> Create Album</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                  <form name="theForm" id="frmalbum" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <h4><label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Album name:</label></h4>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <h4><b><input type="text" name="aname" class="form-control" id="aname" placeholder="Enter album name"  /></b></h4>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                      <h4><label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Album type:</label></h4>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <h4><b><select name="atype" id="atype">
                        <option value="English">English</option>
                        <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>
                        </select></b></h4>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                      <h4><label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="text">Album art:</label></h4>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <h4><b><input type="file" name="picToUpload" class="form-control" id="picToUpload" placeholder="Enter album art" /></b></h4>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">        
                      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="cnfrm()"><h4>Create</h4></button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ><h4>Close</h4></button>
                </div>
         </div>

    </div>
 </div>
```

The code for submitting the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cnfrm()
{
var aname=document.getElementById('aname').value;
var x=document.getElementById('picToUpload').value;
    if(x=="")
    {
        alert("No album art selected");
    }
    else
    {
        var c=confirm("Do you want to add the album?");
        if(c==true)
        {
            var f = document.getElementById("frmalbum");
            f.action="createalbum.php";
            f.submit();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to upload files with bootstrap with drag and drop, or by selecting multiples files you should try http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

Comment: checked it and didn't find much use :( I need a proper js/css file and integrate it with the modal. I need at least the first two requirements to be fulfilled, the other three I will try to complete later